# Asynchronous Loading in UITable cells

Tags: iphone, ios, asynchronous, uitableview

I wish to do asynchronous loading in my UITable cell (I'm using custom cells) as the moment I click on UIButton 'Details', it will hang around 7~8 seconds as it is doing some internet connection for the checking of status. The only thing that requires loading is only the '(2) Book Status' as shown below:

[image]

I've done my research but so far I only found solutions such as lazy loading, which is largely meant for loading of images. Would anyone give some advice for how to do asynchronous loading for text, preferably with some examples? Thanks alot in advance :)

Comment: For that you need to use the pagination from server side

Comment: @neon Actually normally my cells are within a page, not that I have many pages to display.

Comment: So are integrate the pagination or not

Comment: I haven't tried, but I think it will help you. Download the code for "AsynchronousImageView" which is inherited from "UIImageView". Replace it with "AsynchronousText" and inherit it from "UILabel". And change the same related things in .m file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually u need to do lazy loading for values in uitableviewcell. display value when available.

Refer [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) a sample project from apple which loads all values in cell along with image Asynchronously

Comment: In this demonstration just image Asynchronous load but question for the load the cell Asynchronous.

Comment: it loads all values in cell along with image Asynchronously

Comment: Yes, thanks Samuel, I just need to load the cell containing status. :)

Answer (score 0):

For the Asynchronous load the cell followings are resources where you can get the idea.

1. [NMPaginator](https://github.com/nmondollot/NMPaginator)
2. [Source Code](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/18876-paging-pagination-load-more-uitableview.html)